# Admob Ads with Python Subset For Android (PGS4A)

Tags: java, android, python, android-studio, admob

I'd like to have advertisements in an android App I've written and built using PGS4A. I've done my research and all, but there doesn't seem to be any online resources that explains how to do that just yet. I haven't much knowledge on Java either, which is clearly why I've written that in Python. Has anyone found a way to achieve that? If not, how difficult would it be to convert the project files into an Android Studio (or even an Eclipse) project? (so then one can just implement the ads following the Java Admob documentation found everywhere)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To access Java already implemented version you can use pyjnius. I tried to use it for something else and I didn't succeed. Well, I yielded pretty quickly  because it wasn't necessary for my project.

Otherwise, I am afraid, you will have to implement it yourself from scratch.
I never heard about a finished solution for your problem.

If you succeeded to use PGU, it wouldn't be so hard.
If not, well, I wish you luck, and put your solution online for others.

There is an Eclipse plug-in for Python. I think that Android studio does not support PGS4A. Never needed it. Console is the queen.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't succeed. PGS4A is quite lacking compared to others, so I didn't use it, and I wouldn't recommend it to anyone for the time being. Since my application was simple, I just ended up redoing it on Java Android Studio.Thank you very much for taking your time to reply though!

Comment: Ow, don't say that! I used PGS4A for one very complicated project and it proved as excellent! The thing is, whether you know pygame, and few other tricks, and everything works nice and cool. Did you try Pyjnius? Did you try PGU (pygame GUI utilities)?